# Why does my subroutine, which handles a double-click event on a listbox, not work?

Tags: vb.net

I have declared a Sub that is meant to trigger when the listbox 'lstStudents' is double-clicked. However, it does not trigger when this happened. There can't be an error in the code itself as it is auto-generated. Why does the code not function as expected? The code is below:

```
Private Sub lstStudents_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstStudents.DoubleClick
       Msgbox("test")
End Sub
```

The message box is only present for testing purposes.

Comment: Open the Exception Settings (Ctrl-Alt-E) and check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Sometimes this reveals hidden exceptions. After debugging, don't forget to reset the settings (there's an icon in the Exception Settings window for this).

Answer (score 0):

Could You try to delete that previous "lstStudents" and add new one then apply the "ListBox1_DoubleClick" on it again to make sure it works.

Otherwise let us know what is going there because I think your code is normally and it should be working 100%.

Comment: I did this. The method works on other listboxes. The only explanation I can think of is that the listbox I am working with is using a listview. Could this affect it in any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "the listbox I am working with is using a listview" ?
More info, please?

Comment: I have added a listview, as a control, to the control collection of my listbox, in order to enable me to use columns within the listbox.